# Minikube operation timed out

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, minikube

```
minikube start
kubectl config use-context minikube
kubectl create ns my-namespace
```

About half the time this succeeds and about half the time I get an error creating the namespace:
**Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: operation timed out**

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a VPN or behind a Proxy?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of configuration variation possible with minikube, so I'm going to have to make a bit of a leap and assume you're running pretty close to the default configuration.

By default, the VM minikube runs on Virtual Box, using a dynamically allocated IP address. Frequently it will be assigned 192.168.99.100, but there's no guarantee that it will get this IP, and it can be something else.

Run `minikube ip` and see if the IP minikube is using is something other than 192.168.99.100. If it is, then check your Kubeconfig and see if the IP address matches.

`minikube start` usually updates your kubeconfig with the correct IP, so try running that if there's a mismatch and it should fix your issue.